# Tag [Economies], [Economy] -> [Economics]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There were only 11 questions affected, both now altered.

I tried to set up a synonym so that future "Economies" tags get pushed to the singular again, but discovered I lack the ability to do so.

Ergo, I leave that to the mods.

Comment: how about `[economics]`

Comment: @Nick T - You know, I thought that's what I *had* been changing them to. Man. Remind me to never try to get anything done during exam week next year.

Comment: Better to let a mod do it instead of clogging the entire front page with RAVEN DREAMERRRRRR :P

Comment: Bah! You can never have too many Dreamers. John Lennon had the right of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: 30 characters can be painful to fill in