# Are tags [Inventory-management] and [economics] really necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123133/how-do-i-get-the-most-buck-for-my-bang) has used the tags [inventory-management](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inventory-management) and [economics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) and has become the only question in either tags. I know [economics] used to exist, as per [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/tag-economies-economy-economics) back in 2011, but it's faded out of use and I don't see the need to have it, since game economies are so specific to the game.

I'm not sure what the process for removing tags is, so:

**Should the [inventory-management] and [economics] tags be deleted?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should the [inventory-management] and [economics] tags be deleted?

Yes.

Comment: [The bit about single-use-tags is no longer true.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5379/23)

Comment: @badp whoops, forget about that.